# lspci can't see driver name in use

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules, pci

When doing lspci, usually we can see a driver in use:

ex:

```
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

If there is no 'driver in use', does it mean really no driver or it may a driver in use but not external module ( kernel built-in module )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kernel built-in modules will also be reported by "kernel driver in use". For example, my system reports a `skl_uncore` driver in `lspci`, and there is no corresponding module in `lsmod`, so it is a driver that is built into the kernel.

On PCI bridge devices, some of them might not need a driver as they are covered by the generic PCI(e) bridge device support in the kernel.